# Check if new entry is already in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I receive user input through QT Creator form. This user input gets passed to a function that writes this input to a CSV FILE. everything works. No problems.

But when some new input is done and the CSV File already contains a row where a specific "column" is equal to the same "column" from the user Input then it should either forget the new entry (user input) and just modify the CSV FILE row on a specific "column" or it should delete the old entry from the CSV File and write the user input as a new entry to the CSV FILE.

```
def check_and_save(newEntry): 

  ### add some new variables to newEntry
  a_count = 0
  b_count = 0
  c_count = 0


  #### what the function should do
  1. check if there is a specific CSV FILE 
     (i.e CSVFILE('StrikeListReport'))

     if the CSV FILE does NOT exist create CSVFILE('StrikeListReport') 
        and write -- new entry -- in a row to it

     else if CSV FILE('StrikeListReport') already exists:

        1. open CSV FILE('StrikeListReport')

        2. go trough each row in CSV FILE('StrikeListReport') and \
           check if --newEntry-- already exist in the 
           CSV FILE('StrikeListReport') based on --new entry[2]-- 
           #(staff_id) 

        3. if --new entry[2] -- already exist in 
           CSV FILE('StrikeListReport')

           the function should either:    

             1. delete the -- old entry -- 
                add (+1) to -- new entry --'s -- a_count -- #new entry[4]
                then write -- new entry -- to CSV FILE('StrikeListReport')

           or :

              2. forget about the --new entry -- 
                 and just add( + int(1) ) to the 
                 -- old entry --'s -- a_count -- # old entry[4] then
                 save / write  CSV FILE('StrikeListReport') with changed 
                 -- old entry --
```

my attempt

```py
###### User Input from QT Creator

staff_firstname = "Jane"
staff_lastname = "DoeDoe"
staff_id = "809564"
store_id = "809"
chosen_incident = " just some text "
strike_comment = " just some text "
date = "2012"



class DoIt:
    def save_and_send_strike_report(self, staff_firstname, staff_lastname, staff_id, store_id, chosen_incident,
                                    strike_comment, date):

        strike_count = 0
        detention_count = 0
        hr_penalty_count = 0



        new_strike_report = [staff_firstname, staff_lastname, staff_id, store_id,
                             chosen_incident, strike_count, detention_count, hr_penalty_count, strike_comment,
                             date]

        with open('StrikeListReport' + store_id + '.csv', "r") as csvfile:

            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";")

            for item in reader:

                    for new_item in new_strike_report:

                        if new_item[2] == item[2]:
                            item = item[5] + 1
                            with open('StrikeListReport' + store_id + '.csv', "a") as csvfile_out:
                                writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out)
                                writer.writerow(item)

                        else:
                            with open('StrikeListReport' + store_id + '.csv', "a") as csvfile_out:
                                writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out)
                                writer.writerow(new_item)
bla = DoIt()
bla.save_and_send_strike_report(staff_firstname, staff_lastname, staff_id, store_id, chosen_incident, strike_comment, date)
```

My outputs are always something like this no matter what I tried. 
The code above is just one of my ways of trying to solve the problem :

1. _csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
2. TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
3. -- it just writes (i) to my CSV File separated by ","
4. -- writes infinitely

Comment: Just wondering if a solution using SQLite would be more appropriate for this application. This sounds like you're using a csv to store a simple SQL-like table. There are ways to update a CSV, but they seem way to inefficient IMO.

Comment: Okay thanks for this advice

Comment: Choose one implementation and one error and describe it in detail with all input and a full traceback (without separate pseudocode; we can read simple code just fine).

Comment: question. how can i show some code i dont have? i am newto codeing and new to stackoverflow. so how can i show some code i need that i totally did not now where to start. i dont get it